# What happens when multiple values are replaced in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example:

```
temp = list(range(1, 11))
print(temp)
>>>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

temp[3:5] = 'a', 'b'
print(temp)
>>>[1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

A source said that replacing values using list indices [start:stop] actually creates an entirely new list, instead of simply updating the current one. Is this the case? It doesn't seem correct to me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090104/how-does-python-store-lists-internally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't.

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> id(x)
36789896L
>>> x[1:4] = 'a', 'b'
>>> x
[1, 'a', 'b', 5]
>>> id(x)
36789896L
```

So it's still the same object. `'a'` and `'b'` do get grouped into a temporary tuple though, which is then embedded into the existing list object without creating a new one.

**EDIT**

In light of boardrider's answer, it's worth mentioning this *can* result in a new list if the original list grows too much, but then this is also the case for appending, extending, and so on; nothing special about slice assignment.

Comment: It seems that the `id` remains the same however: tried this code on my machine: `l = []; li = id(l); while id(l) == li: l.append([0]*100)`. Python memory usage grew by 10 GB, and still was running...

Comment: This probably depends on the implementation of ``realloc``: in CPython, ``id`` is the memory address of the object, so if it were moved it should have changed.

Comment: @mescalinum: `id()` is guaranteed by the Python language to be constant during a life-time of an object. `l.append()` won't change `id(l)` whatever `realloc()` does on a given platform.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your misunderstanding was due to python actually returning a `shallow copy` with list slice actions [:]. But if you use slice to do any permanent changes to the list, it stays as the same object.

example:

```
tmp = list(range(1,11))

id(tmp)
>>> 6591232

print(tmp[::-2])
[10, 8, 6, 4, 2]

id(tmp)
>>> 6591232

print(tmp)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

more about shallow copy: https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html