# isinstance() method returns false answer in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, isinstance

Look at the following code:

```
a = 3
type(a) == object
False
isinstance(a, object)
True
```

How is this to be explained?

Comment: Object is base class. Type is metaclass.

Comment: @Mad Physicist,deleted.

Comment: Object is base-class. int is a sub_class from object. You can check here.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python?rq=1

Comment: `a` is of type `int`, and `int`is a subclass of `object`. When you're using `isinstance(object, classinfo)` method, you're taking subclasses into account whereas using `type(object)` method generally returns the same than : `object.__class__` attribute.

Comment: Python's recommandation is to use `isinstance(object, classinfo)` method to test the type.

Answer (score 3):

Everything is an object in Python, which includes ints, strings, functions and classes. Therefore, `isinstance(a, object)` will return you `True` . But 3 is actually an `integer`, which is a `sub_class` create from `object`. Therefore `type(a)` can equal to `int` only.

I can give you an example.

Suppose we have two classes, Sub is a sub_class of Base.

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        self.kappa='kappa'
class Sub(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

obj=Base()
int_rino=Sub()


print(isinstance(obj, Base))
print(isinstance(obj, Sub))
print(isinstance(int_rino, Base))
print(isinstance(int_rino, Sub))


print(type(int_rino) == Base)
```

The result will be:

```
True
False
True
True
False
```

Comment: based on your terminology I'm guessing that you're confusing baseclass and metaclass

Comment: Much better. I feel like I wrote that exact line "everything is an object in python" earlier today with the exact same emphasis. I'd recommend removing the superfluous comma.

Comment: @ Mad Physicis, ok, sir.

Comment: My mistake. My phrasing was *slightly* different: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51317646/2988730 :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a common construct in most object-oriented languages that support inheritance. When a child class (in your case [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int)) inherits from a parent (in your case [`object`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#object)), it is said to have an "is-a" relationship. That is, an `int` **is a** (or **an**) `object`.

This "is-a" relationship is what [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) is checking. From the docs:

> Return true if the *object* argument is an instance of the *classinfo* argument, or of a (direct, indirect or virtual) subclass thereof.

There is a similar [`issubclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#issubclass) function to check the same relationship for a class instead of an instance of that class. In fact, in most cases, `isinstance(x, y) == issubclass(type(x), y)`.

[`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) returns the exact class that an object was constructed from. That means that checking `type(3) == object` is exactly equivalent to checking `int == object`. Hopefully you can see that that's unambiguously false.

On a related tangent, classes should always be the same reference within a given run of the interpreter, so you can use `is` instead of `==` for comparison. So `type(3) is int` will be true. That's how `==` is implemented for all the types you're ever likely to come across anyway.

Comment: Great answer, however do not oppose `class` and `instance` because classes are instance of Type

Comment: @Florian. I wouldn't say that I'm opposing instances and types. Of course you're right that all classes are an instance of their metaclass (which doesn't have to be `type` or even inherit from it). However, I feel that this is a level of pedantic detail OP does not need and possibly can't handle at the moment. Also, keep in mind that functions like `issubclass` and `isinstance` *require* a class or tuple of classes for their second argument. So classes, regardless of metaclass, do have a special purpose here.

Comment: I had already upvoted, and with the edit, it's perfectly clear and accurate :)  I was not accurate, classes are instance of `Type` **by default**, but it's **not necessarily true**. (for example : in most API using metaclasses as factory pattern)

Comment: That gets me thinking now. I wonder if I can make a plain function into a metaclass by slapping on `__init__` and `__new__` attributes.